# macOS Catalina automount (net drives) broken

Tags: macos, automount, icloud, macos-catalina

I'm currently running a beta of Catalina on a macbook.
Which by the way if you intend to try, save yourself lots of pain and wait for official release, it's as buggy as can be. Security and permission prompts every other minute ...

To properly(setting i've used in previous installs, found on SE) automount to a NFS drive from my ubuntu server, upon installation i replaced the **/net** line in **/etc/auto_master** with :

```
/net            -hosts      -nobrowse,nosuid,locallocks,nfc,actimeo=1
```

What i realize now is that the original auto_master file on Catalina is fundamentally different from previous macOS, seemingly due to the pronounced iCloud integration into the ecosystem.

And you guessed it... i broke the net drive mounting mechanism.
No drive will work **properly from finder "Network" tab**.
Tried SMB, AFP and NFS

What does work if from finder *"connect to server ---> afp://admin@001.003.04.06"* which then prompts the login and mounts correctly.

Subsequently i'm also now experiencing major issues when using icloud, you'd think the macbook is meant to be a frying pan when saving a simple pdf to iclood.

All this to say.. would anyone, pretty please, have the original **/etc/auto_master** file for **Catalina** :D
It's not online yet (as far as i could tell)..

Any *idea/knowledge/suggestion/experience* about usage of iCloud/network drives on Catalina is welcome. Maybe one you smarties already have a custom setup runnning properly.

Thanks !

Comment: PS: one of the major issues i'm having with iCloud drive, is the ability to save files on the **cloud only** and not on the local machine (to save space).  
It's either iCloud drive is ON which copies all documents+desktop files into iCloud but keeps local copy. or its OFF, which not only won't let me save files to iCloud drive, but also doesn't give the opportunity to access the drive at all.

Comment: iCloud is not a remote storage solution. It is not designed to do that at all. It is a distributed document solution with a temporary off-load capability in case your local machine gets too full.

Comment: Correct me if i'm wrong but i'm pretty sure apple's intent with Catalina and moving forward is to use iCloud as a remote storage solution. Such as that your files AND settings are saved on there. Should you buy a new mac, loging into iCloud will be able to clone previous machines, effectively moving away from.. timemachine (on a physical drive you own)

Comment: I don't know. I sincerely hope not, I have 20TB of data here, safely backed up to my own satisfaction on & off site. I don't even use iCloud for my phone snaps, let alone serious work. I use it to keep things like my keychain & calendars synchronised.

Answer (score 1):

```
+auto_master            # Use directory service
#/net                   -hosts          -nobrowse,hidefromfinder,nosuid
/home                   auto_home       -nobrowse,hidefromfinder
/Network/Servers        -fstab
/-                      -static
```